# I am trying to display data values from txt file based on selection select

Tags: javascript, php, list

I am trying to display data values from txt file based on selection select

```
<?php
$lines = file('customers.txt');
?>

<select class="select" style="width: 250px;" name="mylist" id="mylist" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Your Company</option>
        <?php foreach($lines as $line){
       $customers = explode(',', $line);
        echo "<option value='".$customers[0]."'>$customers[0] </option>"; }?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inputid" placeholder="Company Name">
```

and my attempted js

```
<script>
    $(".select").change(function(){
  var res = $(".select").find(":selected").map(function () {
    if($(this).val()!="")
      return $(this).text();
    else
      return "";
   }).get().join("");
  
   $("#inputid").val(res);

 });
</script>
```

My customers.txt data file:-

Customer1,A street,A extension,A zipcode

Customer2,B street,B extension,B zipcode

Customer3,C street,C extension,C zipcode

...etc

On selection Customer1 I want to display in a :-

Customer1
A street
A extension
A zipcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data you want to have in client code (js) somehow. Right now you only embed customer name in html that you can access from js (via option value). If you want to also access remaining data you need to pass it. One solution could be data html attribute (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) which is supported by jquery (https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
<?php
$lines = file('customers.txt');
?>

<select class="select" style="width: 250px;" name="mylist" id="mylist" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Your Company</option>
        <?php foreach($lines as $line){
       $customers = explode(',', $line);
        echo '<option value="'.$customers[0].'" data-line="'.$line.'">'.$customers[0].'</option>'; }?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inputid" placeholder="Company Name">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $("#mylist").change(function(){
      var line = $(this).find('option:selected').data('line');
    $("#inputid").val(line);
  });
</script>
```

Here I add a data attribute called line `data-line="'.$line.'"` that contains whole line from file and add that to every option tag.

Then in js that data attribute of selected option can be read `var line = $(this).find('option:selected').data('line');`.

If you need more control of what is available from the file you can introduce multiple data attributes with selected columns from the file or put it as a json string and read what you want in js.

Comment: Thanx less coding and works 100% already accepted adey_888 but both codes revelant

Comment: How can I have line breaks instead of everything in one line and without ,

Comment: You have a hint in the last paragraph and then accepted answer is more suitable.
You can instead of this: `data-line="'.$line.'"` do this: `data-line="'.str_replace(',', PHP_EOL, $line).'"` so replace commas with new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you?

```
<?php
$lines = file('customers.txt');
?>

<select class="select" style="width: 250px;" name="mylist" id="mylist" required="">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Select Your Company</option>
<?php
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $customers = explode(',', $line);
    echo "  <option value='{$customers[0]}' data-street='{$customers[1]}' data-extension='{$customers[2]}' data-zipcode='{$customers[3]}'>{$customers[0]}</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<textarea id="inputid" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Company Name"></textarea>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#mylist").change(function() {
  var street = $('select option[value=' + this.value + ']').data('street');
  var extension = $('select option[value=' + this.value + ']').data('extension');
  var zipcode = $('select option[value=' + this.value + ']').data('zipcode');

  $("#inputid").val(street + '\n' + extension + '\n' + zipcode);
});
</script>
```